# Fixing macro for siunitx backwards compatibility

Tags: macros, expansion

I am encountering errors with my below code (contained in a loaded `.sty` file; packages appropriately loaded beforehand), which is part of my attempt to ensure [`siunitx3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) compatibility for older code, while maintaining backwards compatibility for Version 2.

```
\expandafter\edef\csname SIUnitXUnitSepParamNameV2\endcsname{number-unit-product}
\expandafter\edef\csname SIUnitXUnitSepParamNameV3\endcsname{quantity-product}

\edef\SIUnitXUnitSepParamName{\csname SIUnitXUnitSepParamNameV3\endcsname}
%
\@ifpackagelater{siunitx}{2021/05/17} {  % main release of 3.0.0
    % already set, as default, above
}{
    \edef\SIUnitXUnitSepParamName{\csname SIUnitXUnitSepParamNameV2\endcsname}
}
```

I later attempt to use this, as follows:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\DeclareSIUnit[\expandafter\SIUnitXUnitSepParamName = \;]\basepair{bp}
       
    
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\DeclareSIUnit[\expandafter\SIUnitXUnitSepParamName = \;]\kilobasepair{\kilo\basepair}
```

I realize that I have errors with my macro substitutions, but my attempts to solve it have been unsuccessful thus far. (I get various errors, amounting to saying that my `SIUnitXUnitSepParamName` definition is invalid, due to not properly expanding.)

Might someone be able to kindly point out my error(s), and ideally provide both a corrected version, and perhaps an improved version, using LaTeX 3 syntax? Feedback or improvements for these particular `\SI` definitions would also be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct `\expandafter`y would be:

```
  \expandafter\DeclareSIUnit\expandafter[\SIUnitXUnitSepParamName = \;]\basepair{bp}
% 1           2             3           45
```

(remember, each `\expandafter` skips one token and expands the next, so above 1 skips 2 and expands 3, and 3 skips 4 and expands 5).

But instead if you're on version 2 you can define the key `quantity-product` to be an alias to the key `number-unit-product`:

```latex
\@ifpackagelater{siunitx}{2021/05/17}
  { }
  {
    \keys_define:nn { siunitx }
      { quantity-product .meta:n = { number-unit-product = {#1} } }
  }
```

then you can use `quantity-product` unconditionally.

Working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{siunitx}{2021/05/17}
  { }
  {
    \keys_define:nn { siunitx }
      { quantity-product .meta:n = { number-unit-product = {#1} } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = x]\basepair{bp}
\DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = x]\kilobasepair{\kilo\basepair}

\begin{document}

\ifdefined\qty
  \qty{10}{\basepair}
\else
  \SI{10}{\basepair}
\fi

\end{document}
```